# Changing font style of a selected List item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listitem

I have a menu drawer with a list that has a custom ArrayAdapter. I wish to change the font style of a selected list item to bold but I'm not sure how to.

From my research it seems that I should be doing it in getView of the custom adapter. Here's my getView, how would I do it?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  return getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
}
```

Edit: Tried to change the typeface in getView as below, but didn't work. tv seems to be always null.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  TextView tv;
  View myView
  myView = getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
  tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.list_content1);
  if (tv != null)
    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
  return myView;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to change the font style for selected item, then it should be done in the itemClickListener and not in getView.

Comment: Hi, I've tried implementing a onListItemClick() but the changes do not seem to be reflected during runtime.

Comment: Can you post your itemCLickListener code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;
TextView tv;

   if (convertView == null)
        convertView = View.inflate(context, android.R.layout.YOURLAYOUT)
        TextView tv  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.YOURTEXTVIEW);
        holder.tv = tv;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        tv = holder.tv;
    }

    //now - find your textview based on your conditions. Just an example.
    tv.setText(getItem(position)); 
    if (tv.getText().equals("changeme"){
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); // Typeface.NORMAL, Typeface.ITALIC etc.

  return convertView;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I've modified my original post with something I've tried in getView, but it's not working.